# How do I chain together 2 forkJoins so the second call can use the data from the first?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I need to be able to chain 2 forkJoins together as the second group of observables requires the output of the first set of observables.

The problem is if I do the second one inside a `.pipe(map(...))` the observable will return another observable rather than resolve group 1 and then resolve group 2. This means I have to have a subscribe in the subscribe and two separate error handlers like this.

```
var o = forkJoin(
    a: getObservableA(),
    b: getObservableB(),
    c: getObservableC()
).pipe(
    map( result => {
        a2: processA(result.a),
        b2: processB(result.b),
        c2: processC(result.c)
    }); 
)

o.subscribe( x => {
    x.subscribe( y => { 
        // It worked, process output {a2:..,b2... etc
    }, errorY => {... errors for part 2 })
}, errorX => {... errors for part 1 })
```

I also tried:

```
forkJoin(
    a: getObservableA().pipe(map(processA(result.a)),
    b: getObservableB().pipe(map(processB(result.b)),
    c: getObservableC().pipe(map(processC(result.c))
).subscribe( x => ... )
```

But that gives an object like `Observable<{a: Observable, b: Observable, c: Observable}>` which means those processX calls aren't being subscribed to and executed.

I don't really need the data from any of the observables, just to fetch the data in group 1 and use it in group 2.

Is there a way to easily chain two forkJoins together which would give one error handler to catch any errors and to avoid nesting subscribes which I've been told is a bad pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need a [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)?

```
forkJoin([
  getObservableA(), 
  getObservableB(), 
  getObservableC()
]).pipe(switchMap(([r1, r2, r3]) => {
  return forkJoin([
    processA(r1), 
    processB(r2), 
    processB(r3)
  ])
})).subscribe(([r1, r2, r3]) => {
  
})
```

It would probably be better practice to chain the call to `processA/B/C` directly after each element inside the first `forkJoin`:

```
forkJoin([
  getObservableA().pipe(switchMap(processA)), 
  getObservableB().pipe(switchMap(processB)), 
  getObservableC().pipe(switchMap(processC))
]).subscribe(([r1, r2, r3]) => {

})
```

This will be faster since we don't have to wait for all the Observables to complete before beginning to process them.

---

You can then put an error handler for all errors inside the `pipe()` with `catchError()`.

```
forkJoin([
  getObservableA().pipe(switchMap(processA)), 
  getObservableB().pipe(switchMap(processB)), 
  getObservableC().pipe(switchMap(processC))
]).pipe(catchError(err => {
  
})).subscribe(([r1, r2, r3]) => {

})
```

Alternatively, put it inside the `subscribe()` callback.

```
forkJoin([
  obs1.pipe(switchMap(processA)), 
  obs2.pipe(switchMap(processB)), 
  obs3.pipe(switchMap(processC))
]).subscribe(([r1, r2, r3]) => {

}, error => {
  
})
```